# Hide Jcombo box item

Tags: swing, jena, ontology

Hello I have a combo box with two items: Expert level and Easy level.
I work on semantic web application in which if a user is an individual of a class called "GoodUSer", hide Easy level element of the combo box and just display the Expert level. 
How can I hide the element Expert Level?

```
private void jTextField1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                      
    OntModel model2=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
   InputStream in =FileManager.get().open("F:ont.owl");
            if (in==null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " +  " not found");
            }          model2.read(in,"");

             String ns="http://www.semanticweb.org/t/ontologies/2016/7/myOWL#";


             OntClass gooduser = model2.getOntClass(ns + "GoodUser");

    // GoodUser is subclass of User
            OntClass user1 = model2.getOntClass(ns + "User");


         Individual indiv = gooduser.createIndividual(ns + jTextField1.getText());

                if ((indiv.hasOntClass(gooduser))){


                levelCb.setSelectedItem("Expert");
```

// I do not know what to do next to hide Expert level item from combo box if user is from GoodUser
}

Comment: `How can I hide the element Expert Level?` - just remove it from the combo box.

Comment: @camickr, how? I mean which method to use?

Comment: Read the JComboBox API for methods that allow you to remove items from the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Use [removeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItem(java.lang.Object)) to remove an item from a `JComboBox`, essentially 'hiding' it:

```
levelCb.removeItem("Expert");
```